# How to obtain the line element with inverse metric coefficient than that of Schwarzschild line element?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, singularities

The Schwarzschild solution could simply be expressed as

$$ds^2=-(1-2GM/r)dt^2+(1-2GM/r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\phi^2 \; .$$

Is it possible that we could obtained a new metric into the form as

$$ds^2=-(1-2GM/r)^{-1}dt^2+(1-2GM/r)dr^2+r^2d\phi^2 \; ?$$

If possible what are the steps and procedures that should be done to derive it in formal way.

Comment: The question title does not seem to mention the question asked.

Comment: The phrase “inverse metric” usually refers to $g^{\mu\nu}$, the matrix inverse of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. Is that what you are talking about? If so, you don’t use it to make a line element.

Comment: I think you should change the title of the question to one that really try to express the real context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schwarzschild metric can be derived requiring spherical symmetry and vacuum solution ($R_{\mu\nu} = 0$) for the metric: $$ds^2 = -Adt^2 + Bdr^2 + Cr^2d\theta^2 + Dr^2sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$$ where A, B, C and D are functions of $t$,$r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$

You can calculate the Christoffel symbols and the components of the Ricci tensor for the alternative metric. After that, verify if it can be a vacuum solution. If not, what is the energy-momentum tensor associated.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed of calculating the Christoffel and Ricci tensor components to obtain the line element that I mentioned. But it is not possible to obtain the alternative metric from conventional procedure. If possible please explain it.

Comment: Elaborate it please. I am not getting the final line element that I was expecting by following the same way as you mentioned.

Comment: "You can calculate the Christoffel symbols and the components of the Ricci tensor for the alternative metric." How?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to obtain a new metric of the form you have given, but it would not describe a black hole.

To derive this metric, we start with the original Schwarzchild metric:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}s^2 = 
-\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}t^2+
\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2+
r^2\mathrm{d}\phi^2
\end{equation}

Now we can write this in matrix form as:
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{r^2}{\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)}
\end{bmatrix},\ \textrm{for }\mu,\nu=t,r,\phi
\end{equation}

For the next step, we need to find the inverse metric $g^{\mu\nu}$. This is given by:
\begin{equation}
g^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)}{r^2}
\end{bmatrix},\ \textrm{for }\mu,\nu=t,r,\phi
\end{equation}

Now we can use the Christoffel symbols to calculate the Riemann curvature tensor. The non-zero Christoffel symbols are given by:
\begin{align*}
\Gamma^t_{tr} =\Gamma^r_{tt} &= \dfrac{GM}{r^2} \\
\Gamma^r_{rr} &= -\dfrac{GM}{r^2}\left(1 - \dfrac{2GM}{r}\right) \\
\Gamma^\phi_{\phi r} = \Gamma^r_{\phi \phi} &= \dfrac{1}{2}r\left(1 - \dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1} \\
\Gamma^r_{\phi \phi} &= -r\left(1 - \dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}

Using the Riemann curvature tensor, we can calculate the Ricci tensor and scalar curvature. However, in this case, it is easier to use the fact that the Ricci tensor is proportional to the metic. In other word, we can write:
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu}=\dfrac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

Using the original metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, we find:
\begin{align}
R_{tt}=R_{\phi\phi}&=+\dfrac{2GM}{r^3} \\
R_{rr}&=-\dfrac{2GM}{r^3}
\end{align}

Substituting these values into the new metric, we obtain:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}s^2&=\left(1+\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)dt^2+\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\phi^2
\end{align}

Comment: I am in need of the above line element. I want that solution from formal way not through coordinate transformation but by using the Christoffel's, ricci tensors and so on. Yes, it certainly leads to some physicality problem, let it be for now. I will solve this issue later.

Comment: Oh ok, I will edit my mensage using the formal solutions

Comment: I'm not sure about your reasoning that because the $dt'$ coefficient goes to zero as $r' \rightarrow \infty$ this implies the spacetime is unphysical. This behaviour clearly comes from the coordinate transformation used $r' \propto 1/r$. Moreover, this exact argument could be used with the original Schwarzschild metric. An even simpler example, take Minkowski space under the transformation $t \rightarrow 1/t'$. The $dt'$ component vanishes for $t' \rightarrow \infty$ (or singular for $t' \rightarrow 0$), but this obviously comes from the coordinate transformation! The same is true here.

Answer (score 0):

Your other metric is not a solution to [Einstein field equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096). The metric coefficients $g_{00}$ and $g_{rr}$ are related to each other through the equation below ($u\equiv r^2/R^2$). Using it one can check whether the new metric satisfies it.
$${\rm e}^{-\lambda}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} u} \left( {\rm e}^{-\lambda}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}u}{\rm e}^{\nu}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}u}\left(\frac{1-{\rm e}^{-2\lambda}}{u}\right)~{\rm e}^{\nu}~.\tag{1}$$

The easiest way to do it is to notice that both metrics satisfy ${\rm e}^{\nu}={\rm e}^{-\lambda}$ what simplifies the equation $(1)$ to
\begin{equation}\label{compactform2}
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d} u} \left(\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}u}{\rm e}^{\nu}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}u}\left(\frac{1-{\rm e}^{-2\lambda}}{u}\right),~\tag{2}
\end{equation}
The solution of equation $(2)$ reads $${\rm e}^{-2\lambda}=1+\frac{C_{1}}{\sqrt{u}}+C_{2}~u\equiv1+\frac{\tilde{C}_{1}}{r}+\tilde{C}_{2}~r^2.~\tag{3}$$
The vacuum solution (Schwarzschild solution) corresponds to $\tilde{C_{2}}\equiv0$.

Concluding, the only metric satisfying $~g_{00}\cdot g_{rr}=1$ relation is the Schwarzschild metric (with or without cosmological term).

Comment: I see there is no linkage between the equation (1) you mentioned, if I am not wrong. If possible, I am expecting that line element from formal way using the christoffels, ricci tensor components, and so on. I always get the same Schwarzschild solution what ever my input be.

Comment: I am not sure how to understand your comment. You can write any metric but you have no guarantee that it is a solution of Einstein field equation. I have rewritten my answer to make clear what I have meant.